# Token undefined RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, stripe-payments

I have been dealing with this error for 2 days made some changes got some other error that I corrected and now I'm back to this PLEASE HELP ?

I guess these are all the classes that will help you guys for the solution

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvCjR.png) 
[user.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdD94.png)

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :profile
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end

    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :select_plan, only: :new

  def create
    super do |resource|
      if params[:plan]
        resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
        if resource.plan_id == 2
          resource.save_with_payment
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
 end


    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    end
end
```

Comment: correct grammar help to understand very easily

Comment: correct grammar is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxM6d.png)Where are you setting the `stripe_card_token` attribute on your user? It doesn't seem to be set anywhere in your code.

Also make sure you're whitelisting your controller params, and also sending `stripe_card_token` in your params.

In your `Users::RegistrationsController`:

```
before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create

def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:stripe_card_token, :any_other_params_you need_saved]
  end
```

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    end
end

Comment: I tried to make all the changes i found on my research and im still getting the same error as you can see in the pic ERROR :(

Comment: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-05-05 10:41:43.232330"], ["email", "asdxz@asd.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$KfpnX9AvZpSrHX38DN0ZXOxshW7vBNubaR3e2da8L1CiTjFCDPsVa"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-05 10:41:43.232330"]]
   (10.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1291ms

Comment: Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: undefined):
  app/models/user.rb:12:in `save_with_payment'
  app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `create'

Comment: Right, there's nowhere in your controller where you're actually setting the stripe_token on your user.

Comment: Isnt that part being done by Javascript    if (!error) {
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);